# PHP Facebook API - cannot obtain birthday from API

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-apps

I have a very simple Facebook app based on this authentication code:

```
$session = $facebook->getUser();

if (!$session) {
    $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
               'canvas' => 1,
               'fbconnect' => 0,
               'scope' => 'publish_stream, email, user_activities, user_birthday, user_hometown'
               //'req_perms' => 'publish_stream,email,user_location,user_birthday,user_hometown'
           ));
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = 'FB_URL';</script>";
} else {
    try {
        $uid = $facebook->getUser();
        $me = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = 'FB_URL';</script>";
    exit;
    } 
}

echo "\n === \n";
print_r($uid);
echo "\n === \n";
print_r($me);
```

The output is:

```
=== ID_VALUE === Array ( [id] => ID_VALUE [name] => NAME [first_name] => FIRST_NAME [last_name] => LAST_NAME [link] => PROFILE_URL [username] => USERNAME [gender] => male [email] => EMAIL [timezone] => 2 [locale] => en_US [verified] => 1 [updated_time] => 2012-05-16T13:00:04+0000 )
```

I would expect that after specifying the extended permissions `user_birthday` and `user_hometown` I should get in the array also the information about users' birthday and hometown... but unfortunately these information are missing there...

Am I missing something or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try 'birthday' insteed of 'user_birthday' for 'scope'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some investigation,

Can you try this:  `$me = $facebook->api('/me?fields=birthday');` and

for the scope - you request right permission, it's `user_birthday`

Make sure your `$facebook` object has `access_token`

Take a look and report back, i will try to help.

EDIT:
I don't understand where from you get FB_URL, since you write LoginUrl in `$url` variable
I reviewed your code and suggest you to try this way:

```
if (!$session) {
    $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
              'redirect_uri' => //SET back to your page or whenever you need
               'scope' => 'publish_stream, email, user_activities, user_birthday, user_hometown'          
           ));
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">top.location.href =' . $url . '</script>';
} else {
    try {           
        $me = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();       
    } 
}
```

Additionally validate user access token for all rights 
Get $facebook->getAccessToken(); and debugit here -> [Token debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)

Comment: `$me = $facebook->api('/me?fields=birthday');` unfortunately didn't help me. However, could you be please more specific about `access_token`, some example? Thanks

Comment: `$facebook->getAccessToken();` check what this returns.

Comment: Debug this token as i recommend you in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to update my code according to yours and still the same. I have check the access token on the URL you provided me and the token is valid. Also, in my FB profile I have set up my birthday

Comment: does the token include the scope : user_birthday?

Comment: then your session still exists with unproper permission request. reject all  your access and get new ones. my code will work fine with this.

Comment: how can I reject those access? Logout doesn't helps.

Comment: Facebook -> account settings -> apps then [X] on your app. 
https://www.facebook.com/settings?ref=mb